# How to make low poly ground look better

Tags: 3d-meshes, art, world-design, low-poly

I'm working in Unity and have created some low poly meshes using blender. Currently, the meshes look good, but the ground seems very lacking. I am not sure how to make it feel natural or even look good in general.

Here is a current image
[image]

The ground needs to remain mostly flat due to the game placing flat objects on the top of the plane and the image shows the exact camera angle we are using. But, as you can see in the image, the ground is extremely lacking and it doesn't look like a ground but instead just a flat background color. I've tried textures but it does not look good with the trees and low poly design.

How can I make the ground look better?

Comment: What sort of textures have you tried? What didn’t you like about them?

Comment: I tried grass textures, cartoon textures. They didn't match the low-poly feel. It either makes it too realistic or goofy.

Comment: It looks that boring because its completely flat. `The ground needs to remain mostly flat due to the game placing flat objects on the top of the plane` Why? Can't the game place objects on non-flat terrain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A texture is a simple idea. You say you've tried some and they didn't look good. If you created the texture out of polygons would it look better?

Or better yet, maybe try making  the ground a flat plane made out of triangles, but vary the color of the triangles. Either use shades of green, or have both green and brown for grass and dirt, maybe white for snow if appropriate.

Another idea is make the ground just barely not flat so that you don't have to change your physics but the light hits each poly of the ground just slightly differently to give you a different feel.

Comment: +1 for making the ground "just barely not flat". I think a texture wouldn't look good with the assets in the picture, but a "triangulated low-poly" ground would fit nicely.

Comment: Even if the mesh was far from flat, you can just use a different (plane) collider mesh to keep the physics from changing.